# missing /Shared/EditorTemplates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to edit the Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Boolean.cshtml

file in my c# program to show bolean as yes or no rather than true or false. However this file and folder(EditorTemplates/Boolean.cshtml) is missing.

I am using visual studio 2010 mvc3, but it does not create this folder or file for me.

Only thing in my Shared folder by default is _layout.csthml, _logonPartial.cshtml, and Error.cshtml

How to I get Visual Studio to build these files?

Comment: You could always add them yourself I believe...

Comment: Please try to improve your formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the folder yourself and override the default Boolean editor template. Be sure to name the file `Boolean.cshtml` and declare the appropriate model:

```
@model Boolean

// Your html/code for your editor template
```

Comment: How do I reference the boolean.cshtml once added?

Comment: You don't have to reference it at all. Any Boolean property for which you use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyProperty)` will use your editor template automatically.